# Send WM_POWERBROADCAST to other process

Tags: windows, user32

I have a Windows application that monitors [Windows power management events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-management-events)

How to manually send such events to the process for testing purposes rather than putting the laptop to sleep or hibernate? Is there a way to post PBT_APMSUSPEND to a process for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the message, with the parameters set up accordingly, using `SendMessage`, using the recipient applications main window handle as target.

You might have problems with `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE`, where `lParam` is a pointer to a structure. (Windows usually copies such structures to other processes accordingly, but as this is a message you are not supposed to send yourself, it might be handled differently.)

It would be more prudent anyway to test the real scenario, e.g. in a virtual machine.
While you can test your applications response to a particular message, there are aspects this does not cover

- Some notifications you need to register for (`RegisterPowerSettingNotification`)
- Order and timing of notifications
- Allotted response times
- behavior of the OS depending on whether your return code indicates you did handle the message or not